chaining execution in powershell and premature exit with non-zero code, kills vscode terminal
In vscode terminal (powershell), I was doing the following:
& .\run-prog1.ps1 ; if($EXIT_CODE -ne 0) {echo "###failed"; exit 1; }; & .\run-prog2.ps1

In this case, run-prog1.ps1 exited with a non-zero status, and, the if block executed, and, finally the exit 1 executed, and, this killed the vscode terminal.
Any alternative way to chain executions to happen based on successful exit status codes, and, not kill the vscode terminal in case the program throws a non-zero exit status code.
